# Process Builder - Record Update & Number of DML

Tags: process-builder, governorlimits, dml

In a process builder, if you have a node with multiple "immediate actions" for updating records, do those all get processed as one dml on that record in question or do they each count as distinct transactions?

Example:
We have filters in each immediate action that says update x if account field equals y. The account might match multiple immediate action criteria filters. So trying to determine if for each one it matches theres another dml or if its all batched into one "update" to that record.

(Context: developer trying to consolidate our process builders or move them into apex since we're hitting many cpu limit exceptions).

Thanks

Comment: I believe there are some smart optimizations put into Process Builder to try to group the same SObject records together to do a single batch update together, but separate objects will necessitate addition DML calls.  For what it's worth, the whole process builder is considered one transaction afaik - meaning all those update commands, creating other records, triggering other automation etc is all considered under the same CPU time